# Laravel - symfony/console PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm trying to run composer dump-autoload on a newly installed laravel 5.6, on ubuntu 16.04. The command works on my mac, but not in the server.

I get:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable 
(T_VARIABLE) in ../vendor/symfony/console/Output/Output.php on line 40
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable 
(T_VARIABLE) in ../vendor/symfony/console/Output/Output.php on line 40
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump 
event returned with error code 255
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

php -v on server returns:

```
PHP 7.2.3-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 
11:18:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.3-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 
1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

my symfony/console is versioned - v4.0.6

running composer update works in other dir of the server where I have older version of laravel (5.4), there I have symfony/console v3.3.0

Comment: try composer install or composer update

Comment: This sounds *exactly* like the error you'd get if you were installing v4 of the Console component in a PHP version less than 7.1 - see https://3v4l.org/3boKa. I know you said the server is displaying 7.2, but can you double (or triple) check which version of PHP is being used by Composer? Bear in mind you might have more than one version installed.

Comment: laravel levaral - I did composer install and composer update.
iainn - I've ran composer config platform.php 7.2, how else can I make sure I'm running php 7.2?

Comment: make a route that returns phpinfo();

Comment: lewis4u - yeah I did that, it shows PHP Version 7.2.3 on top

Comment: ok running this works:
/usr/bin/composer7.2-sp dump-autoload
should I make symlink between /usr/bin/composer to /usr/bin/composer7.2-sp?

Comment: Running "composer self-update" might help.  As of this writing, you should have version 1.6.3.

Comment: Cerad - I already did that before, and it's 1.6.3.
Should I just override the /usr/bin/composer with /usr/bin/composer7.2-sp?